# Trying to replace image on hover using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change the colour of an image using jQuery, I am doing this by replacing the image on hover of the parent a element.

I am doing this for several of them so I am using the :nth-child selector to dictate which one will take affect, I will post a sample of the code here there are more a elements in place however in the actual code.

The problem is nothing is happening on hover, thanks in advance for your help - much appreciated.

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery( ".top-icons a:nth-child(1)" ).hover(function() {
        jQuery('img.icon').attr('src', function(i, val) {
            return val.replace(/\.jpgjQuery/,'http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/fst-buyer.png');
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="top-icons cs-element cs-animate" style="opacity: 1; top: 0px;">     

        <span class="full-line"><!-- --></span>

        <a href="http://www.example.com/mortgages/first-time-buyers/" class="icon1 fitem">
            <img src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/thestory-child/images/icons/line.png" class="iline">
            <img src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/thestory-child/images/icons/fst-buyer.png" class="icon">
            <p>First Time Buyer</p>
        </a>        

</div>
```

Comment: Why do you need jQuery anyway? This can be achieved using only css

Comment: @WilliamBarbosa - thanks, I would be really interested to see how this could be done in CSS

Comment: .icon:hover{//your css here }

Comment: @CodeFox thanks for your input although I am trying to replace the image that is being displayed, this I believe is better to do through jQuery? please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: both is suitable, js and css. But I would use CSS if the image which should be shown is always the same, you can do it with backgrounds and so on (div with background as image change on hover -> .icon:hover{background:...;})...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give your image an id, so its easier:

HTML :

```
<div class="top-icons cs-element cs-animate" style="opacity: 1; top: 0px;">

  <span class="full-line"><!-- --></span>

  <a href="http://www.example.com/mortgages/first-time-buyers/" class="icon1 fitem">
    <img src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/thestory-child/images/icons/line.png" class="iline" id="myfirstImage">
    <img src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/thestory-child/images/icons/fst-buyer.png" class="icon" id="mysecondImage">
    <p>First Time Buyer</p>
  </a>

</div>
```

now simply just do this :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#myfirstImage").hover(function() {
      jQuery(this).attr('src', 'https://www.google.it/images/srpr/logo11w.png');
    });
});
```

this was with jquery.

[Jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mavcp2p7/)

there is another way with css,which you use the image as a background of an element:

Html:

```
<div class="top-icons cs-element cs-animate" style="opacity: 1; top: 0px;">
      <span class="iline" id="myfirstImage"></span>
    <p>First Time Buyer</p>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.iline{
  background: #ffffff url("http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools.png") no-repeat;
  display: block;
  height: 150px;
}
.iline:hover{
     background-image: url("https://www.google.it/images/srpr/logo11w.png");
}
```

[Jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ptu1ehsL/)

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery for this seems like overkill.

I would recommend using the CSS :hover selector and change the background-image property.

Here is a pretty thorough guide of what you can do with :hover

http://www.corelangs.com/css/box/hover.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the css way to do. That is changing background on hover using :hover selector. I have another way using JavaScript

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sbn375ww/)

**HTML**

```
        <span class="full-line"><!-- --></span>

        <a href="http://www.example.com/mortgages/first-time-buyers/" class="icon1 fitem">
            <img src="http://www.queness.com/resources/images/png/apple_ex.png" class="iline" />
            <p>First Time Buyer</p>
        </a>        

</div>
```

**JQuery/JS**

```
$("img").hover(function () {
    $("img").attr("src", "http://www.fordesigner.com/imguploads/Image/cjbc/zcool/png20080526/1211810004.png");
}, function () {
    $("img").attr("src", "http://www.queness.com/resources/images/png/apple_ex.png");
});
```

> Note: Using CSS you can not have power to alter the img src, but it
>   has power only if you want the change background-image:url(); on
>   hover. If you want to use img tags i would not suggest you the CSS
>   way.

Comment: Thanks for your input - I believe though the issue is really with selecting the element?